Identities for power of quadratic forms
Let a quadratic form $q=x^TAx$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I want to express $q^k$ in such a way that the terms that depend on $A$ can be separated (in the linear sense of the word) from those that depend on $x$.
For example, if $k=1:$
$$q=x^TAx=\text{Tr}\left(A\cdot xx^T\right)$$
where $\text{Tr}$ is the trace (linear operation).
Do you know of any similar expression for the generic case of $q^k$?

Use index notation:
$$
  q(x)^k = (x_{i_1}A^{i_1j_1}x_{j_1})\dotsb(x_{i_k}A^{i_kj_k}x_{j_k}) = (A^{i_1j_1}\dotsb A^{i_kj_k})(x_{i_1}x_{j_1}\dotsb x_{i_k}x_{j_k}).
$$
This is a contraction between a tensor only depending on $A$ and a tensor only depending on $x$.
